# counter++/counter-- not working as expected

Tags: ios, ios5, uilabel

Below is the code i'm using. If I press addQuanity m_label is set displays one instead of two. If I press addWuantity again m_label shows 2.  Press minusQuantity changes m_label to 3 instead of 2 but pressing minusQuanity again change m_label to 2.  Any ideas on what i'm missing?

Thanks,
Ryan

```
NSInteger counter = 1;
-(IBAction) addQuantity
{
if (counter > 9 )
    return;
[m_label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",++counter]];
}

-(IBAction) minusQuantity
{
if (counter < 1 )
    return;
[m_label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",--counter]];
}
```

Comment: Nitpicking; try to rewrite your title, --counter is not the same as counter-- (which your title suggests).

Answer (score 3):

Are you using the increment (++) and decrement (--) operators as prefixes or as suffixes?  If you use them as suffixes (as you show in your question's title) they will behave as you are describing.  If you use them as prefixes (as you show in your question's body) then they will behave as you intend them to.

When used as a suffix, the expression will return the original value of the variable and then add/subtract one.

```
NSInteger counter = 1;
NSLog(@"%i", counter++);  // will print "1"
// now counter equals 2
```

When used as a prefix, the expression will add/subtract one and then return the value of the updated variable.

```
NSInteger counter = 1;
NSLog(@"%i", ++counter);  // will print "2"
// now counter equals 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Save a line of code and make your program logic easier to understand.

```
NSInteger counter = 1;

-(IBAction) addQuantity
{
if (counter <= 9 )
    [m_label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",++counter]];
}

-(IBAction) minusQuantity
{
if (counter >= 1 )
    [m_label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",--counter]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
[m_label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",--counter]];
```

Try

```
counter -=1;
[m_label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",counter]];
```